# Count of how many times a unique value appears across all columns and rows of a dataset?

Tags: count, stata, unique-values

I have unique IDs in rows where columns are the `ID`s of their 'sent' friends. To get a count of 'received' friends, I need to get a count for how many times an ID appears across all columns and rows of the dataset. This is easy in R, but I'd like to stay with Stata for this project.

| ID | F1_ID | F2_ID | F3_ID | ID_mentions |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 4 |
| 2 | 4 | 1 |  | 4 |
| 3 | 1 | 2 |  | 3 |
| 4 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 3 |

Toy data above. Here, there are four mentions of `ID #1`, three mentions of `ID #4`, etc.

I want to generate a variable containing the count of how many times each `ID` value in the first column is mentioned in any column of the data set. This is illustrated in the `ID_mentions` column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I wrote something in this territory. You would need to install this with `ssc install tab_chi`

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. For more info, type help dataex
clear
input byte(id f1_id f2_id f3_id)
1 2 3 4
2 4 1 .
3 1 2 .
4 2 1 3
end

tabm *id

           |                   values
  variable |         1          2          3          4 |     Total
-----------+--------------------------------------------+----------
        ID |         1          1          1          1 |         4 
     F1_ID |         1          2          0          1 |         4 
     F2_ID |         2          1          1          0 |         4 
     F3_ID |         0          0          1          1 |         2 
-----------+--------------------------------------------+----------
     Total |         4          4          3          3 |        14
```

EDIT To count all mentions:

```
gen mentions = . 

quietly forval i = 1/`=_N' { 
    egen work = anycount(*id), value(`=id[`i']')
    su work, meanonly 
    replace mentions = r(sum) in `i'
    drop work 
}

list
```

Comment: Thanks Nick, this package and the help files are informative. Would you know how to extract counts as variable values? E.g., where a new variable column row value is the count of how many times the first "ID" column row value is mentioned in the data set?

Comment: See the help for `tabm`:  you can `replace` the dataset in memory. Otherwise see `egen` for various `any` functions for counting across variables.

Comment: Thanks again Nick. I've queried these files and still cannot find an answer. I've opted to move to R as a result.

Comment: I don't really follow what new variable you want. Is it to be aligned with the original data, or in a new dataset. The description "new variable" is too vague to allow me to guess.  Can you update your question with a concrete example?

Comment: Hi Nick. I've edited the original post to add a fourth column illustrating what I'm looking for.  Thanks!

Comment: OK. So please look at the EDIT.